# Need permissions uploading .aspx page to my own sharepoint site

Tags: permissions, html, aspx

When I try uploading a .aspx to the "pages" library on my own sharepoint site, I get this message:

Sorry, you don't have access to this page
Awaiting approval. We'll let you know about any updates.
(send a message to request permission)

It is incredibly frustrating. I've sent myself a message asking myself to give myself permissions, but I can't see this request anywhere, or the option to give myself permissions. I already have "full control" from what I can see.

My ultimate goal is to serve a react single-page-application within sharepoint. That's another can of worms. I just renamed the index.html from the bundle to .aspx, and plan to upload my js/css/images to the pages library as well. I'd love a less nonsensical solution to deploying my app if anyone knows :) Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One does not simply dump a stand alone web site into SharePoint. Here are a couple things for you to consider:

- You do not appear to have "full control". If you did you'd be able to approve those pages yourself.
- While we're on the subject, stay away from the Pages library altogether. That's for use by SharePoint's publishing features. You're already getting bitten by the Approval nonsense, which by the way you can disable by going to Library Settings -> Versioning Settings -> Require Content Approval. Use a normal document library (or better yet, master page gallery) for your JS/CSS/images, and use SitePages for your aspx. **
- Consider using a script editor web part instead of uploading the entire index page in its entirety. If you just upload the page as is it'll be divorced from the site master page, which is what makes SharePoint SharePoint. It enables navigation, the site actions, and lots of other goodies. But I guess what you decide will be informed by what you're actually trying to accomplish.

(**Yes there are better ways to do this, but the OP seems a little inexperienced in Sharepoint and I'm trying to get him into business with as little trouble as possible)

Comment: Thank you Derek - yes I am a total newbie. Fortunately someone on my team is very experienced at Sharepoint, and our client needs it on SP, but I was just trying to get a demo together over the weekend. Little did I know the frustrations it would cause. I greatly appreciate your response and will try your suggestions tonight!

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem, but this blog article looked too advanced for me to solve.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/25442.web-sensitive-files-and-sharepoint-sharepoint-2010-2013-and-2016.aspx

I gave up on IE11.  I told everyone in the company to use Chrome instead of IE now.